# Is there anyway of making a non-hosted paypal button safe?

Tags: php, security, paypal, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I have made a PHP shopping cart and paypal button linked to the cart where you can make a purchase

For this reason I couldn't use an encrypted or hosted button, as I wanted to have a dynamic variable so I used the non-hosted button

I know this means users can change the price or make the payments go to their own Paypal,

But I want to know is there a way of encrypting the button myself or making it safe?

I have read conflicting things about using paypal IPN to help prevent this,

but my real question is, is there a way/service/API which can make my non-hosted button safe?

It 100% needs to take the total price variable from my cart and show it on paypal, I cannot set just one price amount

I have been searching for an answer for weeks, maybe it is because I am rather new to this or maybe I am searching for the wrong thing, but any help or point in the right direction would be great as right now I don't even know/understand if there is a way to make a non-hosted button safe

Thanks and hope my question isn't too stupid (not asking for code, asking if this is possible!)

Comment: what you do is verify the details from paypal using IPN or other. let the user change anything they like, it wont matter. same applies for any payment gateway

Comment: I read this, is this definitely okay and would it be time consuming etc? The website if for a friend and not for me so I want them to be okay with it

Comment: cant say its hard: `if ($value_sent==$value_recived){//great }else{//bad}`

Comment: I meant for my friend when she gets payments come through, will it be easy for her to see if it is fraudulent (she isn't very techy)

Comment: Thanks for that though, it is actually very helpful as this is the first time I have made a site with a paypal button :)

Comment: she should ignore paypal's notification of payment, because the one you send her will have verified the details

Comment: The one I send her? Ah I am confused, should I be sending her a notification too from the cart/checkout?

Comment: I would. Although paypal is trying to be more than just a payment gateway. I would send her a definitive response that payment is correct. But i dont know the full user case here - so its your call. if she only sells wigits at $10 each, its going to be easy to tell from the paypal email if there is any fraud going on. If she sells hundreds of items at different prices, it would be a lot harder. -- why not just install for her any fre open source ecommerce code and let that deal with this all

Comment: just a very small merchandise shop with around 10 low priced items, so I should make it send her an email to confirm the payment is okay?

Comment: Would highly recommend to use [PayPal-PHP-SDK
](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK). Even if it is a small store. There is a working example - [Pizza App](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-php)

Comment: @pizza app can I integrate this with the code I have already? Thanks